# React Native with Unity as a library

Tags: react-native, unity-game-engine, mobile

I'm developing an app that has minigames, podcasts and videos. My idea is to use Unity for the minigames and to use React Native to build the UI and the video and audio players. I tried to find references about using Unity as a library and React Native, but I didn't find anything. It would be great to hear if someone tried this approach and how it worked.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but there's no easy NPM package for this - you will need to write your own native modules, and even then it may not work quite as well as you hope. See [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/uaal-example) for more reading.

Comment: I dont see the point of the requirement, as both react native and unity serve same purpose, that is to build an app for mobile devices. Onother thing is that you would like to use react for the UI layer of your app in unity, for which I would try [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/reactui-a-webgl-react-based-ui-system-147903) asset out, which I havent. I would be glad to know your experience with it if you try it and if it worths it

Comment: the correct question title would be "React with Unity as a library", without the native, in my picky humble opinion :)